# ACF attachment custom field in rest response

Tags: uploads, advanced-custom-fields, attachments, rest-api, block-editor

I created an extra select option ACF field for media uploader and I would like to retrieve the associated values in Gutenberg MediaUploader onSelect.

[image]
Is there a workaround for this case?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Currently facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check out ACF to REST API - https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api

You can optionally turn on/off which fields you want to enable.

```
// Enable the option show in rest
add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/field_settings/show_in_rest', '__return_true' );

// Enable the option edit in rest
add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/field_settings/edit_in_rest', '__return_true' );
```